# Two root accounts, what to do?

Tags: ubuntu, security, root

I'm on Ubuntu 15.04 and today I've been reading an article about Linux security from [this](http://www.sevagas.com/?How-to-secure-Linux-users-26) link.

Everything went good until the part of UID 0 Account

> Only root should have the UID 0. Another account with that UID is
>   often synonymous to backdoor.

When running the command they gave me, I found out there were another root account. Just after that I disabled the account as the article do but I'm sort of afraid of this account, I can find him on `/etc/passwd`

```
rootk:x:0:500::/:/bin/false
```

And in `/etc/shadow`

```
rootk:!$6$loVamV9N$TorjQ2i4UATqZs0WUneMGRCDFGgrRA8OoJqoO3CCLzbeQm5eLx.VaJHeVXUgAV7E5hgvDTM4BAe7XonW6xmup1:16795:0:99999:7::1:
```

I tried to delete this account using `userdel rootk` but got this error ;

```
userdel: user rootk is currently used by process 1
```

The process 1 is systemd. Could anyone give me some advice please ? Should I `userdel -f` ? Is this account a normal root account ?

Comment: I strongly suspect this error is simply because they have the same UID (0).  I just did a test by creating a second user with an existing UID and it was reported as being the first one in `/etc/passwd`.  I also doubt that removing that account could have any impact on the machine since files and processes refer to the UID and not the username.  It would be advisable (although **most likely not required**) to have a recovery disk handy but I would remove it and restart the machine without any worry.

Comment: Remove what? Entry from passwd & shadow or remove the whole account using `userdel -f` ?

Comment: Removed rootk from `/etc/passwd` & `/etc/shadow` ; rebooted and everything is good now, root is being the only one shown as root user
Thank you for your help !

Comment: Either case, try to run some root-kit detector, as you could probably have been infected by one.  `rootk` is too suspicious name, and having a non-disabled password is worse a symptom of having been defeated by a trojan horse.  By the way, don't remove the entry, just insert some letter at the password field to disable it, as it will give you clues to know how did you get infected.

Comment: @DarkHeart, Nope, I'm afraid not... but having a `rootk` account with a supposed valid password (not disabled) is a strong symptom of some network exploit or misuse of the root account by the local user. As we use to say: "Do trust the Holy Virgin, and don't run...".  By the way, do you think I'm a sixteen years old guy with no experience in unix/linux? :(

Comment: @DarkHeart, well, I accept it as such, and you're welcome.  This is my first post in this forum and I don't know the joking level of the parteneurs :)

Comment: May want to check if `/bin/false` is the genuine file by running `sudo dpkg -V coreutils`. If it's been altered, please consider reinstalling everything. Ubuntu 15.04 has been EOL for 6 months, so any existing and future security holes aren't going to be fixed, so you may want to install a newer version such as 16.04.

Comment: A bit OT, but some Unix-systems - like FreeBSD - comes (came?) *default* with a second root-account - `toor` (root spelled backwards) - both with UID #0.  This could be used by a second administrator, or as a way to log-in if you forgot the password to `root` or you deleted the *root*-line in your password file.  Another reason may be if you wanted to be able to use different shells - eg. `root` = bash, `zoot` = zsh, `toor` = tcsh.  On Linux though, it's very suspicious.

Comment: @LuisColorado I'm currently doing this, thank you for the advice - 
MarkPlotnick checked and everything seems good, thanks :) - 
BaardKopperud Yeah I've heard of it but my Ubuntu didn't come with any other root accounts - 
Now I've got a new question, how could I check what the user "rootk" did ? Aren't there any logs file or something ?

Comment: There's no way to check what the user rootk did because that's the same user as root, just a second name and a second password for the same account. You can find when rootk logged in in `/var/log/auth.log`, but if this was malicious then nothing you find is trustworthy (if they can log in as root, they can delete the logs and plant fake ones) and you ***must*** reinstall from known good backups no matter how painful it is. This definitely looks like a deliberate backdoor, except that having `/bin/false` as the shell is weird because it blocks most ways to log in.

Comment: @Gilles  it was first "/bin/bash" and I'm the one who changed it to /bin/false :)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Processes and files are actually owned by user ID numbers, not user names. `rootk` and `root` have the same UID, so everything owned by one is also owned by the other. Based on your description, it sounds like `userdel` saw every root process (UID 0) as belonging `rootk` user.

According to this [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/userdel), `userdel` has an option `-f` to force removal of the account even if it has active processes. And `userdel` would probably just delete `rootk`'s passwd entry and home directory, without affecting the actual root account.

To be safer, I might be inclined to hand-edit the password file to remove the entry for `rootk`, then hand-remove `rootk`'s home directory. You may have a command on your system named `vipw`, which lets you safely edit `/etc/passwd` in a text editor.

Comment: Thank you answering! I feel king of relieved, I thought it was some badass backdoor ! I did as you said, I removed the entry for rootk in /etc/passwd. But there were no `rootk`'s home directory

Comment: @Lulzsec:  This in no way tells us if the `rootk` account was created as a backdoor.  It just means that it can be removed easily.

Comment: I think you have not completely solved the problem.  Check my comments on your question, please.

Comment: Be careful not to run userdel -r, as apparently rootk's home directory is `/`

Comment: @JeffSchaller But if you do, you have also solved the problem, in a way. A malicious user couldn't see any files!

Comment: Better:  use `vipw` if the system has it.

Comment: Thanks for all these answers, I've indeed edited the file using vipw :) Now checking with rootkit checker!

Comment: @Lulzsec did you come to know about conclusion ?

Answer (score 23):

That indeed looks like a backdoor.

I'd consider the system compromised and nuke it from orbit, even if it is possible to remove the user you have no idea what interesting surprises were left on the machine (e.g. a keylogger to get users' passwords for various websites).

Comment: put it in the microwave and buy a new one.

Comment: What makes that look like a backdoor? Does it match any known profiles, rootkits, etc.?

Comment: @Freiheit Well, an additional user with root permissions is pretty much the definition of a rootkit / backdoor. Once somebody was logged in as that user, they could pretty much compromise anything on the system. Even if the account was created for some innocent purpose (amd I have no idea what that would be), someone else could have discovered it and used it maliciously (read up on the Sony DRM that rootkitted Windows for example).

Comment: It's the only way to be sure.

Comment: One thing is a bit odd though. If it is indeed a backdoor, then why is the password disabled?

Comment: @kasperd: The password's not disabled, it's in `/etc/shadow`.  Setting the shell to `/bin/false` (if that hasn't been tampered with) may disable interactive login, but won't prevent the account from being used in other ways.  For example, `sudo -s` will look at the `SHELL` environment variable, not `/etc/passwd`, to determine what shell to run.

Comment: @BenVoigt `!` disables the password.

Comment: @kasperd: Ah, ok.  Might it be a way to get tasks executed periodically as root from a hidden crontab (although the choice of `/` as home directory seems inconsistent with that)?

Comment: @BenVoigt A crontab is not stored in the users home directory but rather as `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/$USER`, so that is a possibility.

Comment: @kasperd: After some more reading, it seems that a default configuration won't process crontab for a locked user account due to `pam_access.so`, but since skipping that test won't break anything, if it were removed from the configuration, the execution of `rootk`'s crontab might go unnoticed for a long time.

Comment: @AaronMcMillin doing as you said deleted the rootk users! Magnificent

Comment: @kasperd Because it was first "/bin/bash" and I'm the one who changed it to /bin/false :)